# How can I enjoy both persistence and the use of a collection in backbone.js?

Tags: collections, backbone.js, persistence

I'm trying to manage survey logic using `backbone.js`. The application is meant to allow the user to start answering questions and continue at any given time, so saving progress is needed. I have a `Question` model that's pretty standard:

```
App.Models.Question = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Then I'd like to have a `Survey` object that remembers the last completed question. My first inclination was to write it as a model, since some sort of persistance is required:

```
App.Models.Survey = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        questions: [],
        currentIndex: 0
    },

    currentQuestion: function() { /*...*/ },
    nextQuestion:    function() { /*...*/ },
    prevQuestion:    function() { /*...*/ }
});
```

When I take this approach, accessing an element inside `survey.get('questions')` doesn't give me a backbone model to use but rather a plain javascript object -- unless I explicitly initialize it with an array of backbone models, which will require extra parsing and bypass how backbone handles RESTful JSON.

On the other hand, using a collection instead of a model will give me Model instances, but then it seems incorrect to save some sort of persistance (`currentIndex`) for a collection, which isn't meant for managing data. So I'm conflicted - using a `Backbone.Model` will let me save how far along the survey the user got, while using `Backbone.Collection` will allow me to manage the questions in a way that seems more correct, as the survey is basically a collection of questions. What's a good compromise to correctly merge between the two considerations? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep your questions model as is. I would also create an answer model that is relational to the question. So it would have the attributes id, questionID, userID, answerChoice, and timestamp.

When a user gets into your survey, I'd fetch() his answers and throw it in an answers collection.

Since the answer is its own model, each time they answer you can easily save() it to your DB.

Then, in your answer collection I'd have a function that retrieves the latest answer model you want via either timestamp or questionID. I guess it depends on what you actually want.

I think this is what you mean by your description but what do you think?